# Netbeans 9.0/10.0 "Bind" option in right click menu missing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-9, netbeans-10

I am very new with netbeans. I was following an introduction course which shows how to Bind jLabel to a jslidebar. 
 The course shows netbeans 7 and I found similar samples with 8.x.
Steps
Add jslidebar to a form. 
Add jLabel
Right click on jLabel 
Click on Bind

I have installed netbeans 9 and 10 in two different machines but "bind" option is not in the menu or in another menu. Or at least,  is not easy to be found. 
Was it option renamed or removed on ver 9/10?  Is anything missing in my installation? 
Thank in advance for all. 
Regards

Comment: Netbeans 9 and 10 are the first releases after the IDE was migrated to the Apache foundation, it may just be that the feature got lost in translation. For the time being you may want to stick to Java 8 and Netbeans 8 to do your assignments.

Comment: It's even missing in Netbeans 11. Could anybody find information about this? Maybe beansbinding is not supported anymore, just like the swing application framework?

Answer (score 0):

The first results of my investigation are that Netbeans 9+ has dropped the use of beansbindings.

This is what [pull request #300](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/300) on the netbeans github repository seems to indicate.

You can still compile an older (Netbeans 8) project after downloading the `org.jdesktop.beansbinding` jar from [the maven repository](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jdesktop/beansbinding) for example, and adding it as a JAR dependency to your project. However, you won't be able to edit the bindings themselves using the Netbeans 9+ UI.

I haven't yet found a way to replace this with an equivalent solution. I tried reproducing what PR#300 mentioned above is doing, but that doesn't seem to work properly (at least with Netbeans 9 and JDK 9.0.4).

I'll edit this response if I do find a neat way of doing this.